# HOW DO I FIX "CANNOT GET" USING NODEJS MONGODB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mern

I m testing a simple Get api with postman, but i am getting "cannot GET".

**server.js (in the root folder)**

````
```const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


const items = require('./routes/api/items');




const app = express();

//body Parser middleware

app.use(express.json());

//Db config

const db = require('./config/keys').mongoURI;

//const db = "mongodb+srv://gkmm:123123123@cluster0-bo4ln.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority"

//Connect to mongo

mongoose
    .connect(db, { useNewUrlParser:true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
    .then(() => console.log('MongoDB Connected...'))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

    const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

    app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`));


//Use routes

app.use('./routes/api/items.js', items);```
````

**routes(root folder)/api/items.js**

````
```const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router();

//Item Model

const Item = require('../../models/Item')

//@route GET api/items
//@des Get AAll Items
//access public

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    Item.find()
        .sort({ date: -1})
        .then(items => res.json(items));
});

module.exports = router; ```
````

Running into this error while trying to test my API, i checked my paths are correct, my database is connected. but i have no idea why is it returning 404 not found.

Answer (score 1):

After looking through your code, @ the line which you ask app to use your routes

````
//Use routes
/* You are telling the route to go through e.g. <yoururl>/./routes/api/items.js/
   in order to reach your GET in items.js
*/
app.use('./routes/api/items.js', items);```
````

To resolve this issue you can edit your app.use to

```
app.use('/test', items) // test is just an example, you can change it to other keywords
```

Then to access your items GET route use "/test/"

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's working now... your solution just worked.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't `app.use('./routes/api/items.js', items);` be `app.use('/api/items', items);` ?